# Does each Spyder ipython console run on a different core/processor or on the same core/processor?

Tags: ipython, spyder, multicore

I am running multiple ipython consoles on spyder. I am wondering if all these ipython processes run on the same core or in different cores for each process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems so. From task manager ---> performance ---> logical process,  we can have the idea about which processers are used by how much.